# Opening image files with Sentinel 2 toolbox

Tags: remote-sensing, toolbox, sentinel-2, sentinel-snap

[image]Anyone worked with the Sentinel-2 toolbox/SNAP? It doesn't support sentine-2 data to be opened directly. I tried opening  .safe, .zip and .xml files.

[image: I tried to open both safe and zip file. Find the error attachments below.]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Please *edit* the question and tell us how you tried to  open the data. The Sentinel Toolboxes usually require the accompanying metadata and therefore you should try to open the `.SAFE` or `.zip` file instead of each granules `.jp2`

Comment: Have you tried File -> Open -> MSI_S_.....5654.SAFE ? or did you try to open the manifest.safe?

Comment: I tried as follows in sentinel 2 toolbox: 1) File->Open Product->S2_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_......zip     2) File->Open Product->S2_OPER_PRD_MSIL1C_......SAFE->manifest.safe

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? If so, please post an answer so we can consider this question closed.

Answer (score 5):

After unzipping, you should find an xml file inside the root directory with the same name as the zipped file. Select the xml file and be patient because opening the file takes a little while. You can then view the data per band, or right click on the scene name to open an RGB composite.

[image]

Normally this should also work directly from the zip file.

However, you should note that the zip files are sometimes corrupted during the download, which seems to be te case with your file. In other words, I think that you are doing the right things and that the software is OK, but that the error comes from the file.

Comment: I exactly followed the procedure you have shown above. In sentinel toolbox-2, it doesn't support the data at all (be it .SAFE, or .xml format). In SNAP toolbox it supports .xml file but it fails after some time giving this error: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.GetShortPathNameA(Unknown Source)
 at org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.Utils.GetShortPathName(Utils.java:45) at org.esa.s2tbx.dataio.Utils.GetIterativeShortPathName(Utils.java:54) etc......May be its wrong with my OS (Windows-8 64 bits) or data I have  downloaded.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot reproduce your problem (it worked with all my images). have you tried to open the .jp2 directly in another software (.e.g the latest QGIS) or to open another image in SNAP ?

Comment: Last time, SNAP toolbox was working well with Landsat data. Now, when I open Landsat-8 data, it displays "SNAP limited functionality window" and says I have opened raster products which contain different raster sizes". The details are provided in this link https://senbox.atlassian.net/browse/SNAP-1. Still I can open Landsat data. I can also open individual .jp2 images in Qgis for Sentinel-2 product.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem with the Sentinel-2 toolbox. After selecting the XML file within the product we can select one of the Sentinel-2 readers and then we get a similar error message. We also have Windows-8 64 bit.

Comment: I have Windows 7 so I cannot test, but this look more like a bug than a technical issue. Have you reported it on http://forum.step.esa.int/t/welcome-to-the-sentinel-toolbox-exploitation-platform-forum/8 ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all I recommend to go to the official SNAP (Sentinel Application Platform - that's the real name of the software) [website](http://step.esa.int/main/download/) and get the latest version:

SNAP in some parts is still under development thus it can be that you are using an outdated version which was missing the S2 reader. After you have done that and opened SNAP go to "File->Open Product...". Now you have multiple options to open an image:

1. Read the main xml which is included in the .SAFE folder. should be something like S2A_OPER_MTD_SAFL1C_PDMC_20151201T155831_R121_V20151128T084811_20151128T084811.xml. 
   1.1 This will open all tiles included in the product. If the product contains multiple UTM zones, you have to decide which tiles you want to load (e.g. tiles from UTM35 or 36) 
   1.2 Additionally you can decide which resolution you want to use. You could either load all bands in their original resolution or you could resample the bands to 10, 20 or 60m
2. Navigate to the Granule folder included in the .SAFE folder. Here you can navigate into one of the Tile folders and select it's xml. By doing so, you can open a single tile and don't have to open all tiles of one UTM zone.